# Sending string variable in JSON from arduino yun to firebase

Tags: json, curl, arduino, firebase

I'm trying to send a json  from arduino yun to firebase via a curl POST.
All the other data (int, float) converted through String() are correctly sent but the "timer" one which is originally a string can't go through. Any ideas ?

```
// Measure the humidity
float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
float temperature = dht.readTemperature();

// Measure light level
int lightLevel = analogRead(A0);

// Time
String timer = getTimeStamp();

// Firebase post
Process p;
p.runShellCommand("curl -k -X POST https://xxx.firebaseio.com/data.json -d    '{ \"Timestamp\" : "timer",\"Humidity\" : " + String(humidity) + ",\"Temperature\"  : " + String(temperature) + ",\"Lightlevel\" : " + String(lightLevel) + "}'");
```

Comment: I think you need a `+` to concat the `timer` String with the rest of the curl command

Answer (score 0):

Although, I haven't worked on Firebase but to create json string I was using below code and its working perfectly:

```
String jsonString = "{\"temperature\":\"";
jsonString += temperatureC;
jsonString +="\",\"humidity\":\"";
jsonString += humidity;
jsonString +="\",\"other_value\":\"";
jsonString += otherValue;
jsonString +="\"}";
```

Hope it will help you in some way.

Comment: Yes it works great but apparently only for int/float variables, not String variables ...

Comment: It should work for string too. You can accept my answer if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It worked by using following line:

```
  Process p;   
  p.runShellCommand("curl -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X POST -d '{\"name\":\"arduino\",\"value\":\"15\"}' http://localhost:1234/temp");
```